# LWJGL: How to set transparency to an image?

Tags: image, textures, transparency, lwjgl, alpha

I hope you understand me, because my English is very bad :D

I am using LWJGL with Slick-Util. And i have a 2D-texture without transparency.
Is there a pissibility to set the alpha-value of every pixel of these texture so i can see the textures behind?

Note, that my texture is non-transparent and i try to change that programmatically.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to make the image transparent.  To do this it should be a PNG.  Download a program such as GIMP from which you can edit the transparency of pixels, you can search 'removing the background of an image in GIMP' or something similar if you cannot workout how to do this.

Then back in java call `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` at the beginning of your program to enable blending (transparency).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to do is changing the transparancy of a non-transparent image programmatically

Comment: Oh, well in that case I would load the image into a BufferedImage using ImageIO.read(), you can then edit the red, green, blue and alpha values of each pixel.  You'll then have to figure out how to load it back into slick/LWJGL.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your idea is great, there are possibilities to convert images from a bufferedimage to a texture (sais google :D ) i gonna try that as fast as i can!